# RecyclerView.Adapter do hide some texts when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView.Adapter` for a horizontal scrolling.
but when I scroll to left or right, some titles is missing/hide.

```
public class ProductHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductHorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ProductModel> mProductItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private View.OnClickListener mClickListener;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ProductModel> favoritesModel;
    private Helpers helpers ;
    // data is passed into the constructor
    public ProductHorizontalAdapter(Context context, List<ProductModel> products) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mProductItems = products;
        this.mContext = context;
        helpers = new Helpers();
        this.favoritesModel = helpers.getFavorites(context);
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapters_home_horizental_products, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductModel productModel = mProductItems.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(productModel.getTitle());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(productModel.getFirstImage()+"?h=210");
        Glide.with(mContext).load(uri).into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mProductItems.size();
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myTextView;
        ImageView mImageView;
        View adapters_home_favorites;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            myTextView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapters_home_name_product);
            mImageView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapters_home_image_product);
            adapters_home_favorites = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapters_home_favorites);
            itemView.setTag(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        }
        

    }


    public ProductModel getItem(int id) {
        return mProductItems.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(View.OnClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

where is the my problem?

---

**updated**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_home, parent, false);
    SliderView SliderView = layout.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
    home_popular_recyclerview = layout.findViewById(R.id.home_popular_recyclerview);
    home_newest_recyclerview = layout.findViewById(R.id.home_newest_recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    home_popular_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
    listPopularProducts = new ArrayList();
    productPopularHorizontalAdapter = new ProductHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(),listPopularProducts);
    home_popular_recyclerview.setAdapter(productPopularHorizontalAdapter);


private void getPopularProduct(){
    Call<List<ProductModel>> call = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getApiService().Products("","","1","1","10","","");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductModel>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductModel>> call, Response<List<ProductModel>> response) {


            listPopularProducts = response.body();
            productPopularHorizontalAdapter = new ProductHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(), response.body());
           // productHorizontalAdapter.setClickListener(getActivity());
           home_popular_recyclerview.setAdapter(productPopularHorizontalAdapter);

            productPopularHorizontalAdapter.setClickListener(onItemClickListener);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error sliders",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why you have two variables with same `List<ProductModel>`?

Comment: I removed it. but it does't solved. it was just a variable.

Comment: I see no issues in the Adapter code. I suspect the problem is in the Fragment/Activity in which the Adapter is instantiated. We'll need to see that code.

Comment: @GavinWright updated my question .

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding creating adapter instance multiple times.

```
productPopularHorizontalAdapter = new ProductHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(),listPopularProducts);
home_popular_recyclerview.setAdapter(productPopularHorizontalAdapter);
```

Remove above  code from `onCreatView(...)` method because your are constructing adapter inside on

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductModel>> call, Response<List<ProductModel>> response) {


            listPopularProducts = response.body();
            productPopularHorizontalAdapter = new ProductHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(), response.body());
           // productHorizontalAdapter.setClickListener(getActivity());
           home_popular_recyclerview.setAdapter(productPopularHorizontalAdapter);

            productPopularHorizontalAdapter.setClickListener(onItemClickListener);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change this method to the following:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductModel>> call, Response<List<ProductModel>> response) {
        listPopularProducts = response.body();
        productPopularHorizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This way, you're telling the already created `Adapter` about the new data, rather than re-creating the `Adapter` every time the data changes.

And the call to `setClickListener()` can be moved to `onCreateView()`.

Comment: If you want to post the project (or a slimmed down version of it) to Github, I'll gladly take a look.